# Place View on Windows 8.1 Tab lock screen

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I have a set of pages which are developed with XAML for Windows 8.1 RT.

The application looks fine and works as expected but a part of the requirement is that a particular view has to be placed on the lock screen. There are no interactions required on the lock screen.

I have searched for quite some time and still no luck.

My question, is it possible to place a view on the lock screen, like possibly a widget?
If possible, what is the right approach?

Step by step instructions are really appreciated, as I am relatively new to XAML and Windows 8.1 RT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

You can add your application to the lock screen notifications as described [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh779720.aspx).

Apps can however change the lock screen background image, maybe that fits your needs as well.
See [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Personalization-App-sample-9ebfe147) for how to use the LockScreen API.